# Changing JavaScript object definition style causes canvas to stay blank

Tags: javascript, html, class

I'm making an HTML5 game using the canvas tag and I'm trying to change the way I define a class I have created in JavaScript and I had it working with one definition style and when I tried to define it in another style it stopped working.  I am not sure what I did wrong as I am just getting familiar with JavaScript.  When I tried the other style of defining, my canvas just doesn't work and nothing appears on the screen.

Essentially in the version that is not working, I am trying to create the object Player() and then create a new player object with so that I can use the rest of the player.doThis() calls I make throughout the rest of the script.

```
var player = new Player();
```

WORKING DECLARATION

```
var player = {
    color: "#00A",
    x: 10,
    y: playerLocation,
    width: 32,
    height: 32,
    speed: (10/1830) * CANVAS_WIDTH,
    zone: [0, 0],
    //sprite: Sprite("player.png"),
    //spriteImage: new Image(),
    //spriteImage.src =  "player.png",

    draw: function() {
        canvas.fillStyle = this.color;
        canvas.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    },

    drawDebug: function() {
        canvas.font = "normal 7pt Arial";
        //canvas.fillText("Cosine: " + transition , this.x, (this.y-55));
        canvas.fillText("In Zone " + this.zone[0] + " of " + this.zone[1], this.x, (this.y-45));
        //canvas.fillText("Zones " + this.zone[1], this.x, (this.y-55));
        canvas.fillText("X: " + this.x , this.x, (this.y-35));
        canvas.fillText("Y: " + this.y , this.x, (this.y-25));
    },


    determineZones: function(numberOfZones) {
        //this sets the boundaries of the zones
        zoneLocations[0] = 0;
        var gap = CANVAS_WIDTH - (infoBoundaries * 2) - infoWidth;
        for (var i = 1; i < numberOfZones; i++)
        { 
            zoneLocations[i] = (gap / (numberOfZones - 1)) * i;
        }
    },

    update: function() { //all of the controls are placed in here
        if ((keydown.left) || (keydown.a))
        {
            this.x -= this.speed;
        }
        if ((keydown.right) || (keydown.d))
        {
            this.x += this.speed;
        }
        this.x = this.x.clamp(0, CANVAS_WIDTH - this.width);

        if(scene == SCENES.length)//this would added controls for perhaps that last boss levels
        {                       
        }
    },

};
```

NOT WORKING DECLARATION (that I am trying to get working)

```
function Player()
{
    this.color = "#00A";
    this.x = 10;
    this.y = playerLocation;
    this.width = 32;
    this.height = 32;
    this.speed = (10/1830) * CANVAS_WIDTH;
    this.zone = [0, 0];
    //sprite: Sprite("player.png"),
    //spriteImage: new Image(),
    //spriteImage.src =  "player.png",

    function draw()
    {
        canvas.fillStyle = this.color;
        canvas.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }

    function drawDebug()
    {
        canvas.font = "normal 7pt Arial";
        //canvas.fillText("Cosine: " + transition , this.x, (this.y-55));
        canvas.fillText("In Zone " + this.zone[0] + " of " + this.zone[1], this.x, (this.y-45));
        //canvas.fillText("Zones " + this.zone[1], this.x, (this.y-55));
        canvas.fillText("X: " + this.x , this.x, (this.y-35));
        canvas.fillText("Y: " + this.y , this.x, (this.y-25));
    }


    function determineZones(numberOfZones)
    {
        //this sets the boundaries of the zones
        zoneLocations[0] = 0;
        var gap = CANVAS_WIDTH - (infoBoundaries * 2) - infoWidth;
        for (var i = 1; i < numberOfZones; i++)
        { 
            zoneLocations[i] = (gap / (numberOfZones - 1)) * i;
        }
    }

    function update()
    { //all of the controls are placed in here
        if ((keydown.left) || (keydown.a))
        {
            this.x -= this.speed;
        }
        if ((keydown.right) || (keydown.d))
        {
            this.x += this.speed;
        }
        this.x = this.x.clamp(0, CANVAS_WIDTH - this.width);

        if(scene == SCENES.length)//this would added controls for perhaps that last boss levels
        {                       
        }
    }
}
var player = new Player();
```

Anyways, if there is something I am doing incorrectly for defining this javascript class please let me know.

Comment: You need to do `this.update = function() { ... }` instead of `function update() { ... }`

Comment: ...or pull the method definitions out of the constructor function and define them afterwards on the prototype with `Player.prototype.update = function() { ... }`.

Comment: I wish either of those worked but still no change in the page.  This is the page I am trying to get working http://game.kstacey.com/testing.html and it works here http://game.kstacey.com/

Comment: @KyleStacey Check your console (ctrl+shift+j in chrome). Any errors?

Comment: Getting closer to it now.  Current error: Unable to get property of 'x' of undefined or null reference

Comment: My player doesn't show up but thanks to all of your guys' help it is back to a state where I can continue debugging on my own.  Thanks so much guys!

Comment: It's all working now!  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are creating methods using `function functionName() {}` instead of `this.functionName = function() {}` (note the `this` part, it's important). Unfortunately, you can't do `function this.functionName() {}` because that's a syntax error.

You could see this by doing `console.log(player.update)`, and you would see that it is undefined.

The solution: use this when creating your functions.

```
this.draw = function() {
    canvas.fillStyle = this.color;
    canvas.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}

this.drawDebug = function() {
    canvas.font = "normal 7pt Arial";
    //canvas.fillText("Cosine: " + transition , this.x, (this.y-55));
    canvas.fillText("In Zone " + this.zone[0] + " of " + this.zone[1], this.x, (this.y - 45));
    //canvas.fillText("Zones " + this.zone[1], this.x, (this.y-55));
    canvas.fillText("X: " + this.x, this.x, (this.y - 35));
    canvas.fillText("Y: " + this.y, this.x, (this.y - 25));
}


// So on

this.update = function() { //all of the controls are placed in here
    if ((keydown.left) || (keydown.a)) {
        this.x -= this.speed;
    }
    if ((keydown.right) || (keydown.d)) {
        this.x += this.speed;
    }
    this.x = this.x.clamp(0, CANVAS_WIDTH - this.width);

    if (scene == SCENES.length) //this would added controls for perhaps that last boss levels
    {}
}
```

Alternatively, you could attach functions to the `prototype` object. For example:

```
function Player() {
  // Non function declarations here
}
Player.prototype.draw = function() {
  // Whatever
}
Player.prototype.drawDebug = function() { // etc.
}
```

The advantage is you save memory, especially since you probably won't be reassigning to these properties (that is, you won't write `player.draw = function() { /* New function here */ }` will you? It's okay if you do that, even with the prototype method, it just won't save memory.

The (possible) disadvantage is that `player.hasOwnProperty("draw")` or `player.hasOwnProperty("drawDebug")` will return false (even though `player` has that property). Another disadvantage is that those functions won't be able to directly access any `var` declarations in the constructor.